# Android Emulator Crash a few seconds after App start on Android Q

Tags: android-emulator, android-10.0

After starting the App after a few seconds the crashes with the follow Log

```
E/chromium: [ERROR:context_group.cc(433)] ContextResult::kFatalFailure: too few uniforms or varyings supported.
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xda6f95e0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xc6280cc0)
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008b49
    glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008b49
    glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008b4b
    glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008b4b
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008b4a
    glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008b4a
E/chromium: [ERROR:context_group.cc(433)] ContextResult::kFatalFailure: too few uniforms or varyings supported.
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xda6f95e0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xc6280cc0)
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008b49
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008b49
    glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008b4b
    glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008b4b
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008b4a
    glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008b4a
E/chromium: [ERROR:context_group.cc(433)] ContextResult::kFatalFailure: too few uniforms or varyings supported.
```